# How to track changes to status of transactions in Access?

Tags: database, ms-access

I'm building an Access database that is fed from an Excel dump off a website for transactional data. These transactions all have a unique identifier, but the status will change as the transactions are processed.

Previously, we would keep the weekly Excel dumps and go digging if we needed to analyze changes in status. Our 'master' data sheet was a 40,000 row Excel file run from the latest dump, meaning we lost old Status data. I have no access to the backend database (if there is one?) where all this information is stored, only the Excel-generated reports.

Now that I am migrating our data into Access, what are some options for capturing the different stages a particular transaction might go through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One fairly straightforward way to do it would be to create an [ArchiveTable] table with the same structure as your Main table (in Access, `Copy > Structure Only`), then add a [ArchivedOn] date/time column to [ArchiveTable].

When you get a new Excel sheet, you can import it into Access (e.g., via `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` in VBA), then do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO ArchveTable (fieldname, fieldname, ..., ArchivedOn)
SELECT fieldname, fieldname, ..., Now() AS ArchivedOn FROM MainTable
WHERE MainTable.TransactionID IN (SELECT TransactionID FROM ImportTable)
```

...then do some "sanity checks" on the data in [ArchiveTable] to ensure that everything got copied before proceeding with...

```
DELETE FROM MainTable
WHERE MainTable.TransactionID IN (SELECT TransactionID FROM ImportTable)

INSERT INTO MainTable (fieldname, fieldname, ...)
SELECT fieldname, fieldname, ... FROM ImportTable
```

Comment: This is great. Extra thanks for the VBA idea, will be exploring that as well!